# Chat client in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, chat

If I create an application for iPhone, how can I get notified of chat messages I receive? Does receiving messages from the server happens through Push notification or Application has to poll to server in a regular time interval.

I guess that for each time a new message comes the server would send a notification to the app, and once the app receives the notification, the app pulls the message from the server.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look up XMPP protocol/servers :) therein lies your answer.

Theres a iPhone framework called XMPPFramework which will help.